# Deleting expired push subscription endpoints from db which is created via service worker

Tags: push-notification, notifications, service-worker

I implemented push notification using service worker. I am storing the endpoints in my db. How can I delete the old subscription entry from db when the current subscription changes/expires. "pushsubscriptionchange" event I am listening in service worker. But it is not fired when I changed the notification subscripion to "Always block on this site" in chrome settings. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that revoking notification privileges via site settings will ever trigger the `pushsubscriptionchange` event on the service worker.

Instead, I think what you could do is detect a rejection of the `registration.pushManager.subscribe()` method from your client pages. As per step 9 of [the specification](https://w3c.github.io/push-api/#pushmanager-interface) for `subscribe()`,

> If not granted, reject promise with a DOMException whose name is
>   "NotAllowedError" and terminate these steps.

So I think that's what you'd end up being able to detect in the scenario that you describe.

As for which subscription endpoints to clean up in that scenario, I'd say you should clean up all of them? The user has opted-out of notifications, so I don't believe any of the existing endpoints would be used moving forward.